# DB2/400 SQL : Does the "USE" statement exist under DB2/400?

Tags: sql, db2-400

On `MySQL` or `SQL Server` database, the `USE` statement allows me to work in the right schema.

Is there on `DB2/400` SQL the equivalent command?

I do not want to work with the command `CHGCURLIB` because our schema names often exceed 10 characters.

thanks for your advices

Comment: Have you ever looked at WRKQRY? I seem to recall STRSQL too. Though it's been like 15 years for me... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-txQQh2Fng https://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/sql/query-management (Query Management Queries too)

Comment: Have you tried DB2 documentation?

Answer (score 1):

SET CURRENT SCHEMA = 'xxxxxxxx'

see [V7R3 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzqualun1.htm) about unqualified names

Comment: OK, Thanks for your answer !